# Haskell Noob question: What's wrong with my append function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, append

I'm trying to write a Haskell append function... Here's what I have:

```
myappend :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
myappend [] x = x
myappend [x:xs] y = x : myappend xs y
```

But it's giving me an error:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = [a]
    When generalising the type(s) for `myappend'

So, obviously there's something wrong with it but I can't see it... What's wrong with my append function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The constructors of the type [a] are:

```
[]  The empty list
(:) Cons operator (just a regular infix constructor)
```

So, you must use:

```
myappend :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
myappend [] x = x
myappend (x:xs) y = x : myappend xs y
```

The syntax

```
[x:xs]
```

is pretty much equivalent to

```
[(x:xs)]
```

which matches a list with one element, a non-empty list, and has type

```
[(x:xs)] :: [[a]]
```

I recommend reading [this page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor) if you want to understand the constructor and pattern matching concept.

Comment: Ahah! Stupid square brackets. I see it now! What was I thinking!? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The pattern in the second case of the function should just be `(x:xs)`, not `[x:xs]`:

```
myappend (x:xs) y = x : myappend xs y
```

`x:xs` matches an element followed by a list, the parenthesis are just there to make it syntactically clear what belongs to that pattern. `[x:xs]` would match a list containing `x:xs`.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no `[]` brackets in
`myappend (x:xs) y = x : (myappend xs y)`

`[1,2,3]` and `1:2:3:[]` are different ways of defining the same list.
So that `[x:xs]` matches one item list consisting of another list.